# Can I add random viewport colours in 2.79 like in 2.8?

Tags: materials, 3d-view, shaders

I was wondering if I can add random viewport colors for better visibility like the [new feature added in 2.8](https://youtu.be/3G0OxL2lfLs?t=21), but in 2.79 (maybe an add-on) since my PC doesn't support 2.8 due to my hardware limitations. I know that I can add materials to individual objects and change their viewport colours manually, but it's too much of work and unfeasible for large scenes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following add-on randomizes the viewport color. It works for both Cycles and Blender Internal. Save the file into `2.79\scripts\addons` and activate if through the preferences. The add-on creates panel in the 3D View properties (<kbd>N</kbd>) titled *Randomize Viewport Color*.

[image]
[image]

In order for the viewport material to be applied for Cycles you need to have a material applied that uses nodes. This is a safety feature, because otherwise changing the viewport color would also change the material color. A limitation for Cycles in 2.79b is that the viewport color is tied to the material. Every object with the same material will have the same color.

*Please keep in mind that this is a quickly written add-on and may have some areas that could be improved.*

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Randomize Viewport Colors",
    "author": "Robert Guetzkow",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Properties",
    "description": "Randomizes the viewport colors of all objects",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "3D View",
}

import bpy
import random


class RandomColorSettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    use_viewport_color = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Enable Viewport Color",
        description="When checked and update is pressed the viewport coloring will be enabled for all materials.",
        default=True)


class RANDOMIZE_VIEWPORT_COLORS_OT_update(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "randomize_viewport_colors.update"
    bl_label = "Update"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        if context.scene.render.engine == "CYCLES":
            for mat in bpy.data.materials:
                # Make sure that nodes are used, otherwise this will change the actual material color
                if mat.use_nodes:
                    if context.scene.use_viewport_color:
                        mat.diffuse_color = (random.uniform(0.0, 1.0),
                                             random.uniform(0.0, 1.0),
                                             random.uniform(0.0, 1.0))
                    else:
                        mat.diffuse_color = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        else:
            for obj in bpy.data.objects:
                obj.color = (random.uniform(0.0, 1.0), random.uniform(0.0, 1.0), random.uniform(0.0, 1.0), 1.0)

            for mat in bpy.data.materials:
                mat.use_object_color = context.scene.use_viewport_color

        return {'FINISHED'}


class VIEW3D_PT_randomize_viewport_colors(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_label = "Randomize Viewport Colors"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(context.scene, "use_viewport_color")
        layout.operator("randomize_viewport_colors.update")


classes = (
    RANDOMIZE_VIEWPORT_COLORS_OT_update,
    VIEW3D_PT_randomize_viewport_colors
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.use_viewport_color = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Enable Viewport Color",
        description="When checked and update is pressed the viewport coloring will be enabled for all materials.",
        default=True)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.use_viewport_color


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still doesn't solve the problem completely. I would like to add random colors directly as I create the new objects for better viewport readability like in 2.8. With this addon, I would have to create different materials for various objects and for addon to work which is too much of work for large scenes. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: That is the limitation for Cycles in <=2.79, the viewport color is tied to a material. I don't think there is a workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple addons for it. I use **random_material_viewport_colors**. But as far i know, these addons do random material color, not object. So you need to create material for every object you need to be random colored.

Comment: Not true, you can set the viewport color in 2.79b as well.

Comment: Yes, but i mean addons can do random colors only for materials. But i can be wrong.